# Vault Drive export using Search Term "in:trash AND owner:me". owner:me behaviour correct?

Tags: google-vault-api

We have found a strange edge case and I would like some advice as to how "owner:me" works with the Vault API.

Vault retention is turned on.

User joebloggs@domain.com has had a lot of drive files and he deleted them 6 months ago.    The user was then renamed to old-joebloggs@domain.com 2 months ago.

When we try to Search or Export using the Account old-joebloggs@domain.com and Search Term "in:trash".  The deleted files that belong to this user via joebloggs@domain.com are not returned. Only any files that old-joebloggs@domain.com owned.

However, if we Search or Export using the Account old-joebloggs@domain.com and Search Term "in:trash AND owner:me".  All of the deleted files that belong to this user are returned.

Is this a valid use of the "owner:me" search operator? It appears to work, but should it? I cant find this documented anywhere.

I was led to believe that owner:me was connected with the currently logged in session. Does providing the Account in the Search act like the session?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

- The Vault documentation advises to use the full email address when using the `owner:` Drive search operator. See [this Help Center article](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2474474#drive_account) for more information. Quoting:

> Note: Enter the account as the complete email address, such as user1@example.com or groupA@example.com.

- The `owner:me` operator is a shorthand reused throughout several Google services (including UIs and APIs) and it's indeed, contextually, points to the current active session user.
- I can only speculate that when you use `owner:me` on Vault Drive search, it may reference the internal ID for the current session user (instead of the email address). Then this would explain why both `old-joebloggs@domain.com` and `joebloggs@domain.com` owned files were returned, since the internal reference for those email addresses should be the same. But again, this is purely speculation since I wasn't able to find any documentation that backs up this theory.

My recommendation would be to reach out to [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) (Since Vault is a Workspace only service) and confirm if this was intended.

I hope this info helps, cheers!